# How to stop a leg from sliding?

Tags: friction

One of the legs of a bed is bent (I believe it buckled). The bent can be corrected to be straight, however under the application of load to the bed, the leg will slowly return to the bent position. My goal is to fix the leg in place and stop it from sliding.

**My current idea is to increase friction between the bed leg and floor.** As a first pass, I tried putting an old rubber slipper underneath the bent leg after correcting it(best I could come up with). It seemed to help a bit, but on heavier load (eg: a person getting on and off), the bending happens again.

I believe the material of the bed leg is some sort of plastic, and that of the floor is granite.

[image]

Comment: I think you would have to test those yourself because you don't normally apply those materials against each other. All you need is a pull scale, a weighted block and a granite surface plate. I doubt numbers involving sandpaper are going to be reliable though. If you apply plastic against sandpaper the surface finish is going to be wildly different in the very next pass because the plastic has been all chewed up so the values aren't going to be consistent or reliable. Not to mention that sandpapers vary wildly by composition and grade. What is the application?

Comment: Bent leg of object, keeps sliding under load. Want to stop it from @DKNguyen

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Imagine a bed with plastic legs. Suppose at a certain height, one of the legs get bent. To prevent the bending from happening, I want to keep a high friction material underneath @DKNguyen

Comment: Hmm if the leg is flexing then stopping it from sliding is not going to fix the problem. Instead it will just buckle in place without the foot sliding. But a soft rubber pad would stop the sliding.

Comment: it is very possible that the bending is caused by the bed being moved sideways ... if the leg is not able to slide on the floor,  then the horizontal force would bend it ... a picture would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few possible solutions you can try to stop the leg from sliding:

Furniture Grippers: You can buy furniture grippers, which are small pads that go underneath the legs of furniture to provide more friction and prevent sliding. These are available in many different sizes and shapes, and can be easily attached to the bottom of the bed leg. Look for grippers that are specifically designed for use on hard floors like granite.

Rubber Pads: Another option is to use rubber pads or discs underneath the bed leg. These can also be purchased at most hardware stores or online. The rubber material will help provide more grip and prevent sliding.

Anti-Slip Tape: Anti-slip tape is another option that can be used to increase friction between the bed leg and the floor. This tape has a rough surface that provides more traction, and can be easily cut to size and applied to the bottom of the bed leg.

Glue or Adhesive: If none of the above solutions work, you can try using a strong adhesive or glue to attach the bed leg to the floor. This should be a last resort, as it may damage the floor if you ever need to remove the bed in the future. Use a strong adhesive that is designed for use on plastic and granite surfaces.

Before trying any of these solutions, make sure the bed leg is straightened as much as possible to prevent any further bending. Good luck!